# zero-inflated negative binomial regression for time series data in R using glmmTMB

Tags: r, time-series, glmmtmb

I am struggling to set up the correct `formula` for a zero-inflated negative binomial regression model in R which accounts for time series data. I read through a lot of manuels and blogs however I still don't really understand how to define the panel setting.

I want to use the `glmmTMB` package and have a df which has `time` and `county` as grouping IDs.

Here is a fraction of my df:

```r
  county  time  region           y         x1           x2        x3
    <fct> <fct> <fct>           <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>
  1 01001 2010  2                   0      53155      -0.282    -0.997  
  2 01001 2011  2                   1      53944       0.0873   -0.955  
  3 01001 2012  2                   0      54590       0.400    -0.797  
  4 01001 2013  2                   2      54907       0.627    -1.05   
  5 01001 2014  2                   3      55136       0.371    -0.858  
  6 01001 2015  2                   1      55221       0.116    -0.505  
  7 01001 2016  2                   0      55049      -0.452    -0.315  
  8 01001 2017  2                   0      55036      -0.566     0.258  
  9 01001 2018  2                   0      55200      -0.850     0.539  
 10 01001 2019  2                   0      55380      -0.992     0.372  
 11 01001 2020  2                   0      55639      -1.22      0.400  
 12 01003 2010  3                   0     175791      -0.168    -0.0510 
 13 01003 2011  3                   5     179523       0.144    -0.107  
 14 01003 2012  3                   0     183226       0.371    -0.123  
 15 01003 2013  3                   0     187114       0.570     0.130  
 16 01003 2014  3                   0     191205       0.400     0.302  
 17 01003 2015  3                   0     195121       0.0873    0.433  
 18 01003 2016  3                   1     199510      -0.254     0.556  
 19 01003 2017  3                   0     203360      -0.481     0.583  
 20 01003 2018  3                   0     208107      -0.793     0.558  
 21 01003 2019  3                   0     212830      -0.822     0.497  
 22 01003 2020  3                   0     218289      -0.935     0.439  
 23 01005 2010  6                   0      27699       0.684     0.645  
 24 01005 2011  6                   0      27546       1.65      0.355  
 25 01005 2012  6                   0      27469       1.79      0.973  
 26 01005 2013  6                   0      27321       2.02      0.695  
 27 01005 2014  6                   0      27119       1.99      0.556  
 28 01005 2015  6                   0      26932       2.96      0.650  
 29 01005 2016  6                   0      26614       1.59      0.589  
 30 01005 2017  6                   0      26201       1.48      0.595  
 31 01005 2018  6                   0      25782       0.655     0.898  
 32 01005 2019  6                   0      25361       0.570     1.32   
 33 01005 2020  6                   0      25026      -0.0831    1.78   
 34 01007 2010  1                   0      22610       0.542    -0.830  
 35 01007 2011  1                   0      22746       0.684    -0.958  
 36 01007 2012  1                   0      22769       0.939    -0.546  
 37 01007 2013  1                   0      22754       1.42      0.255  
 38 01007 2014  1                   0      22653       1.05     -0.121  
 39 01007 2015  1                   0      22604       0.314     0.00468
 40 01007 2016  1                   0      22572      -0.0263    0.238  
 41 01007 2017  1                   0      22580       0.286     0.305  
 42 01007 2018  1                   0      22527       0.0873   -0.318  
 43 01007 2019  1                   0      22493       0.0305    0.219  
 44 01007 2020  1                   0      22374       0.0589    0.255  
 45 01009 2010  1                   2      56692       0.0873   -0.524  
 46 01009 2011  1                   1      57140       0.542    -0.646  
 47 01009 2012  1                   0      57466       0.797    -0.825  
 48 01009 2013  1                   0      57623       0.712    -0.735  
 49 01009 2014  1                   0      57645       0.598    -0.763  
 50 01009 2015  1                   0      57710       0.144    -1.03   
 51 01009 2016  1                   0      57704      -0.339    -0.677  
 52 01009 2017  1                   0      57667      -0.651    -0.296  
 53 01009 2018  1                   0      57645      -0.878    -0.215  
 54 01009 2019  1                   0      57681      -1.08      0.450  
 55 01009 2020  1                   0      57755      -0.566     0.770  
 56 01011 2010  6                   0      10923       1.14      2.56   
 57 01011 2011  6                   0      10877       2.36      2.39   
 58 01011 2012  6                   0      10779       2.02      1.59   
 59 01011 2013  6                   0      10746       2.22      1.37   
 60 01011 2014  6                   0      10693       2.90      0.144  
 61 01011 2015  6                   0      10678       3.07      0.667  
 62 01011 2016  6                   0      10552       1.73      0.814  
 63 01011 2017  6                   0      10478       1.39      1.15   
 64 01011 2018  6                   0      10352       1.11      2.13   
 65 01011 2019  6                   0      10248      -0.935     0.898  
 66 01011 2020  6                   0      10173      -1.08      1.60   
 67 01013 2010  6                   0      20895       0.655     0.617  
 68 01013 2011  6                   0      20860       1.39      0.439  
 69 01013 2012  6                   0      20730       1.88      0.787  
 70 01013 2013  6                   0      20624       2.16      0.698  
 71 01013 2014  6                   0      20523       1.42      0.508  
 72 01013 2015  6                   0      20354       1.05      0.272  
 73 01013 2016  6                   0      20280       0.740     0.500  
 74 01013 2017  6                   0      20126       0.116     0.241  
 75 01013 2018  6                   0      20025      -0.140     0.834  
 76 01013 2019  6                   0      19828      -0.112     0.586  
 77 01013 2020  6                   0      19726      -0.197     0.720  
 78 01015 2010  3                   0     117149       1.28      0.339  
 79 01015 2011  3                   8     117614       1.37      0.366  
 80 01015 2012  3                   0     117834       1.73      0.344  
 81 01015 2013  3                   0     117714       1.99      0.517  
 82 01015 2014  3                   0     117186       1.79      0.380  
 83 01015 2015  3                   0     116648       1.45      0.155  
 84 01015 2016  3                   0     115883       1.28      0.375  
 85 01015 2017  3                   0     115527       0.826     0.614  
 86 01015 2018  3                   0     115098       0.456     0.745  
 87 01015 2019  3                   0     114618       0.258     0.625  
 88 01015 2020  3                   0     114324       0.0305    0.481  
 89 01017 2010  6                   1      34579       1.99     -0.441  
 90 01017 2011  6                   0      34375       2.19     -0.0899 
 91 01017 2012  6                   0      34228       2.50      0.467  
 92 01017 2013  6                   0      34145       2.84      1.01   
 93 01017 2014  6                   0      34091       1.56      1.71   
 94 01017 2015  6                   0      34079       0.485     1.18   
 95 01017 2016  6                   0      34018       0.0873    0.906  
 96 01017 2017  6                   0      33895      -0.225     0.511  
 97 01017 2018  6                   0      33826      -0.623     0.444  
 98 01017 2019  6                   0      33660      -0.935    -0.496  
 99 01017 2020  6                   0      33427      -1.02     -0.630  
100 01019 2010  6                   0      25700       1.48     -0.0510
```

So far I tried this:

```r
glmmTMB(y ~ x2 + x3 + region + time + offset(log(x1)) + (1|time) + (1|county), 
    data=df, ziformula=~ x2 + x3 + region + time, 
    family=nbinom2(link="log"))
```

But I just don't know if I specified the `formula` correctly by just adding `+ (1|time) + (1|county)`. If someone could help me to understand the logic behind the `(1|var)` expression without referring to the glmmTMB vignettes that would be great and much appreciated.

Comment: The syntax follows `lme4`, where random effects are written as `(coefficients | group)`. A `1` in the formula refers to the intercept, `(1 | group)` means you want to fit a random intercept for that grouping variable. Lots of good information on Ben Bolker's GLMM FAQ: http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html

Comment: "_without refering to the glmmTMB vignettes_" - but, but, it _is_ explained in the vignette.